# Understanding SFINAE Example

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm having trouble understanding this snippet of code which uses SFINAE.

```
template <typename T>
auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,
                                       std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type;

template <typename T>
auto dist() -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, 
                                       std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>::type;
...

decltype(dist<float>()) unifDistFloat;
decltype(dist<int>()) unifDistInt;
```

`dist()` is the name of two different function prototypes, so there is no body containing a return statement. Meaning it never actually return a value of the type `uniform_real_distribution<T>`, or `uniform_int_distribution<T>`.

So shouldn't `decltype` fail trying to call an incomplete function? Or does `decltype` just not call the function at all and instead just evaluate the return type?

Comment: 2nd possibility: `decltype` just *evaluates* the return type.

Comment: `decltype` doesn't actually call anything. All it does is determine the *type* of some expression, *without actually evaluating the expression.* It just looks at the expression and asks "if I did evaluate this, what type would the result be?" This doesn't depend on the bodies of any functions or methods, just the prototypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype` is an *unevaluated context*. It just operates on the type level, so knowing that the body of `dist`, wherever it might be, returns some type X is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`decltype` specifier inspects the declared type of an entity or queries the return type of an expression, thats what it does.

here an alternative usage. for showing that `decltype` cares only for type of any passing expression

```
template<typename U >
static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution <U>>::type
dist(); // NOTE: no function body

template<typename U >
static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, double>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution <U>>::type
dist() 
{
    //return; // NOTE: no return 
}
decltype(dist<T>()) mUniformDistribution;
```

probably the Question why compiler does complain about dist() function as incomplete? i have no idea why is that.

demo example

```
template<typename T >
class Random 
{
public:
    Random(const T& min, const T& max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    T operator()()
    {
        return mUniformDistribution(mEngine);
    }

private:
    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };

    template<typename U >
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value, std::uniform_int_distribution <U>>::type
    dist(); // NOTE: no function body

    template<typename U >
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, double>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution <U>>::type
    dist() 
    {
        //return; // NOTE: no return 
    }
    decltype(dist<T>()) mUniformDistribution;
};

int main()
{
    Random<int> getRandom(0, 9);
    for (int i = 0; i<9; ++i)
        std::cout << getRandom() << '\n';
}
```